# 1/2" Chuck on 3/8" Cordless Drill?

Tags: drill

I need to use a step bit with a 1/2" shank. I only have drills with 3/8" chucks. Is the arbor size on most drills a standard which would enable me to just replace one of the 3/8" chucks with a 1/2" chuck? Is it really that simple?

Comment: What make/model drill?

Comment: It's a Makita from the 90's. I don't have the model number handy.

Comment: There is a reason the drill has a 3/8" chuck.The motor,frame etc is designed for the load /work required to drill a 3/8" hole.You are really goining to be straining the motor to drill a hole that large.If this is more than a one time job the next time you need to replace your drill buy the 1/2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've done some research and it looks like a 1/2" chuck can be used on a 3/8" drill if the chuck is threaded 3/8"x24M. I was able to find a Jacobs MultiCraft (#30598) that should fit my mid-90s Makita.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for Jacobs part number 31037, it's a keyless 1/2" chuck for standard 3/8" drills designed specifically for the purpose of converting them. Your 3/8 drill will be fine with a 1/2" chuck, I've got a few than have been converted, 2 air powered, 1 corded/electric and 2 cordless.  Just treat the drill as you normally would, drilling holes larger than 3/8" with a 3/8" drill has never been a problem.

I converted my first cordless drill for the same reason, needed to use an Irwin Unibit with the large shank.